# is there any way to use HTML/JavaScript and Flash to build an Desktop AIR application and publish it from flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, air, desktop

Is it possible to make desktop Air application by using  HTML/JavaScript and Flash?
Actually I want to make an Air app (which is for desktop) by using flash and want to use HTML , javascript and CSS as well.Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to create an AIR app yourself, by using the Flash IDE? Yes, [that's quite possible](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b21ec24feb12478b70aff-8000.html).

Or do you want to create a web editor made with Flash, which people could then use to create AIR apps? That's also possible, but you will need more than HTML, JavaScript and CSS to do it.  You would have to have a flex compiler set up on the server and use ant tasks to compile and package the code dynamically.

Comment: yes I want to create An AIR app by using Flash IDE but want to use HTML / JS language to create it along with ActionScript.

Comment: That should not be a problem.